# Cocoapods Getting linker issues in SVN checkout Fixed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I have created a Xcode project with cocoa pods and committed into SVN,  When i am taking fresh checkout every time the googleAnalytics or some othe library library is missing.  I have chanhed all the settings like Library Search paths, Framework Search paths and other linker flags and given -Objc, $(inherited). But still same issue.  Below image showing missing library every new checkout

[Image which missing libraries from workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRbwP.png)

Every time when i am taking new checkout pods are missing, I dont want to install pods locally every time. I want commit pods to SVN. Next time when i take fresh checkout it should not give these missing errors.

Comment: Either version your pods directory or run `pod install` after checkout.

Comment: Thanks @shallowThought 5

Comment: But the problem is I am using Jenkins Continuos integration, To Build the project Jenkins takes fresh check out from SVN, how can i give install pods in jenkins

Comment: Sorry, I have given blow commands in execute shel .  Jenkins like this #!/usr/bin/env bash
source ~/.bash_profile
pod setup
pod install --verbose --no-remo-update

Comment: but not installing pods s

Comment: We are the Team with 15 people IOS developers, We integrated jenkins with SVN, We have some cocopods libraries in my project. Those libraries getting failing when build triggered from Jenkins. Because In jenkins     Check-out Strategy always new checkout,  We are also getting issue when we are taking fresh checkout pod missing error for every new checkout

Comment: 1) i want to know why every fresh checkout throwing errors or missing libraries from the project. 2) How can we install cocoa pods in jenkins workspace  projects folder

Comment: I have a project with Cocoa pods, Committed in to SVN. When i am taking Fresh checkout i am getting library file missing error. How can we avoid SVN pod libraries missing error without installing locally. I have already committed my pods in to SVN, But when somebody taking Checkout pod library files missing.

Comment: Please update your question using the [edit button](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40975664/edit). Me and others will answer it.

Comment: @Damodar, have you got solution? actually same issue i have also faced. kindly help me to comeout.